# AttributeError: __delete__ when saving figure in jupyter lab with %matplotlib widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror, jupyter-lab

On jupyterlab (version 2.2.2), if I use `%matplotlib widget` to get interactive figures, I get an `AttributeError` when saving the figure.

Here's an example code:

```
%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sbs
sbs.set()
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os


xy_test = pd.DataFrame({'FeatureX': np.arange(15), 'FeatureY': np.random.standard_normal(15)})

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
sbs.scatterplot(x='FeatureX', y='FeatureY', data=xy_test, ax=ax, s=70, palette='BrBG', legend='brief', edgecolor='k')
fig.tight_layout()
fig.suptitle('N=%d' %(xy_test.shape[0]));

flnm = os.path.join('testfig.png')
if not os.path.exists(flnm) or 1:
    fig.savefig(flnm, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Leading to this error message:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-795a5ae23f02> in <module>
      9 flnm = os.path.join('testfig.png')
     10 if not os.path.exists(flnm) or 1:
---> 11     fig.savefig(flnm, bbox_inches='tight')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in savefig(self, fname, transparent, **kwargs)
   2309                 patch.set_edgecolor('none')
   2310 
-> 2311         self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
   2312 
   2313         if transparent:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2223                 self.figure.set_edgecolor(origedgecolor)
   2224                 self.figure.set_canvas(self)
-> 2225             return result
   2226 
   2227     @classmethod

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     86         if type is None:
     87             try:
---> 88                 next(self.gen)
     89             except StopIteration:
     90                 return False

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in _setattr_cm(obj, **kwargs)
   2064         for attr, orig in origs.items():
   2065             if orig is sentinel:
-> 2066                 delattr(obj, attr)
       2067             else:
       2068                 setattr(obj, attr, orig)

AttributeError: __delete__
```

The figure "saves" to disk and I can open it in some applications, like MS Paint for example, but not in the Windows Photos app. With Photos, I get the "File system error (-2147219196)".

This does not happen in `%matplotlib notebook`. How do I fix this error in `%matplotlib widget`?

Comment: I've had the same issue but find it still actually saves the image. Just has an annoying error (which you could filter out if you needed). try/except could be a quick and dirty solution for anyone who doesn't want to downgrade mpl just yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this issue https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl/issues/252
it seems this error was introduced from matplotlib 3.3.0.
So currently, my solution is downgrading matplotlib to 3.2.2.

```
pip install matplotlib==3.2.2
```

Everything ok in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

A new version of ipyml has been released since then, so can go on with matplotlib 3.3.x and upgrade ipyml

```
pip install --upgrade ipympl
```